# Matrix Multiplication: Connection between contexts.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, vector-spaces

I've been thinking about two well understood uses for matrix multiplication:

1) Composition of Linear Maps. Let $T,U$ be endomorphisms of a vector space $V$, and let $A,B$ be their respective matrices corresponding to these maps wrt some basis. Then $M(T\circ U) = AB$

2) Counting paths in a digraph. Let $G$ be a digraph and $A$ its adjacency matrix. Then $(A^n)_{ij}$ gives the number of paths in $G$ of combinatorial length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.

These, to me at least, seem completely independent. My question follows from a lack of belief in mathematical coincidence: What's the connection between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no coincidence. One way to see it is as follows:

Think of the adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph $G$ as an operator on the vector space $V = \mathbb{R}^G$, i.e. whose canonical basis vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots$ represent the vertices of $G$. A vector
$$
w=\begin{bmatrix}
         w_1 \\
         w_2 \\
         \vdots \\
         w_n
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
in $V$ is a measure on the graph or you may think of it as measuring the quantity of a dye at each vertex. When you apply $A$ to $w$, you propagate the dye, sending $w_i$ units of the dye to each of the neighbors of the vertex $v_i$. In other words, the vector $Aw$ represents the amount of dye at each vertex after one iteration of the propagation step.

Now to see that $A^k_{ij}$ is the number of $k$ step walks from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$, note that $A^k_{ij}$ is the $i$-th coordinate of $A^nv_j$, i.e. the amount of dye at vertex $i$ if we start with one unit of $dye$ at vertex $j$ and propagate $k$ times.